# SQL Server Integer List Table type null to return all

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a Type that holds integer list that can be used in queries. I need to write a where clause on the list parameter and if the list is empty I need to get all. Below is the sql .

```
DROP TYPE  dbo.integer_list_tbltype 
GO
CREATE TYPE integer_list_tbltype AS TABLE (n int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::integer_list_tbltype TO public

GO 

DECLARE @listvalues  dbo.integer_list_tbltype 
INSERT INTO @listvalues values  (3),(4)

CREATE TABLE #MyTable (a INT  NOT NULL)

INSERT #MyTable (a) VALUES (2),(3),(4)

Select * from #MyTable
  Where a in (select n from @listvalues)

go 
DROP TABLE  #MyTable
go
--DROP TYPE integer_list_tbltype
```

So  I need to get 2,3,4 if @listvalues is null , how do I format my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition to check if your table variable is empty. It won't be null, and trying to compare @listvalues to null will yield an error, because it's treated as a table, not a variable.

```
Select * from #MyTable
  Where a in (select n from @listvalues)
  Or (select count(*) from @listvalues) = 0
```

Comment: Why do I get a "Must declare the scalar variable "@listvalues" ? If I add the @listValues Is NULL ?

Comment: @Greens see revised answer please